# Popup window with text entry for iOS/Android with Unity3d

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, popup

I am trying to build a popup GUI window that will display on a press of a button (2d object with collision box).

This window should then have a text entry field and then a button to 'submit' the entered text.

I have tried to use the below code within a script to display the window however this does not seem to get displayed on iOS/Android.

```
public class submitscore : MonoBehaviour {
     public bool doWindow0 = false;
     void Start () {

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {

     }

     void OnMouseDown(){
         doWindow0 = true;
     }

     void DoWindow0(int windowID) {
         if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 20, 100, 20), "Hello World"))
                         doWindow0 = false;
     }
     void OnGUI() {
         doWindow0 = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), doWindow0, "Window 0");
         if (doWindow0)
             GUI.Window(0, new Rect(110, 10, 200, 60), DoWindow0, "Basic Window");

     }

 }
```

Perhaps there is a way to do this native for iOS and Android and just pass the text entered back to Unity?

Comment: Does it get displayed in unity3d's "game" window? Native code sounds way too much work for this kind of basic task.

Comment: @maZZZu it doesnt seem to display no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine on my Unity 4.6:

[image: Screen capture of Submit Score]

If you are not new to Unity you probably have already done this, but you should add a gameObject to your scene `GameObject -> Create Empty` and add your script component to that GameObject `Inspector -> Add Component -> Script -> submitscore`. That is all I did to get it running.

If you have already done this, and still don't see anything, are you getting any error messages?